# Blazor Webassembly : Identityserver4 NullReference AddQueryString

Tags: identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to get a Blazor WebAssembly project working with an existing ASP.NET Core app that uses IdentityServer4(3.1).

When the Blazor app calls the following URL
http://192.168.0.151:5002/connect/authorize?client_id=myWebClient&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.0.151%3A44387%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20openid%20profile&state=5d01e8dfd9ea4c3dbc207839f147bd37&code_challenge=-cXZb1q16t4eTMBaT8-lbeFGRr7V9YIbkl072JPhpQ4&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=query

**I see from the logs that there is a null reference in AddQueryString.**

Not sure how to resolve this.

IdentityServer4 is configured as follows

```
                        ClientId = "myWebClient",
                        ClientName = "My Web Client",
                        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                        RequireClientSecret = false,
                        RequirePkce = true,
                        AllowedScopes =
                        {
                            "openid",
                            "profile",
                        },
                        AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://192.168.0.151:44387" },
                        RedirectUris = { "http://192.168.0.151:44387/authentication/login-callback" },
                        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://192.168.0.151:44387/" },
                        Enabled = true
```

And Blazor as follows

```
"Authority": "http://192.168.0.151:5002/",
"ClientId": "myWebClient",
"PostLogoutRedirectUri": "http://192.168.0.151:44387/",
"RedirectUri": "http://192.168.0.151:44387/authentication/login-callback",
"ResponseType": "code",
"DefaultScopes": [ "openid", "profile" ]
```

With IdentityServer initialised as follows

```
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityServerConfig.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityServerConfig.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityServerConfig.GetClients())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<User>().AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>();
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what I am missing are server pages that handle
login/logout etc. I assumed incorrectly these were present in Blazor webassembly.